# How to reduce or optimize gradle build time in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Please check below image and help me to reduce or optimize gradle build time on android studio

[image]

Comment: Any reason for down voting ?

Answer (score 3):

You can toggle it to work in offline mode so it does not look for dependencies on every build

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Then look for the checkbox **Offline work** and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

If your are building from command prompt ,debug in parallel mode.

Ex:if it was as below previously

```
 gradlew assembledebug
```

[image: without parallel]

then change it to the following:

```
 gradlew assembledebug --parallel
```

[image: with parallel]